# Run windows application for another user

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, administrator, runas

I'd like to run a windows application in the context of another user.  I have an administrator and several user accounts in one machine and I would like to have the administrator start certain applications for each user account (preferably using shell commands).

I tried the runas command but that appears to run in the administrator session as the specified user.  I want to run the application as the user session in the user context (hope that makes sense).

For example, using user administrator I would like to start notepad.exe so that user1 (logged in) can see it appear onscreen.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PsExec for this : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

use with argument : -i  Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session.

ex. This will start IE on other computer 
psexec \client -i "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"

/René

Comment: It also helps to know the session in question so that the application starts in the right session.  Sessions can be queried by using the query session command (found this answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742896/how-to-determine-the-session-id-on-remote-machine-for-usage-with-psexec-i-using )